# best way to install react app manually

Tags: reactjs

i am learning reactjs. And i install my react app by

```
create-react-app first
```

but i want to know is there any manual way to install react app

Comment: To create a react application from scratch?

Comment: i want to add all dependency manually like webpack,babel,etc

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do all of that. And as you mentioned it requires knowledge of webpack and babel if you use jsx

Comment: i had tried npm i -S react but its giving me error                                              npm ERR! code ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END
npm ERR! write after end

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-15T18_22_19_666Z-debug.log

Comment: Run `eject` and it will let you configure all manually

Comment: There are a lot of github issues and stackoverflow threads discussing the same error you are having.

Comment: so should i use create-react-app only because i am a beginner and don't have much knowledge of babel, webpack etc

Comment: If you want to learn webpack/babel then configure it, else leave it to others

Comment: This is a dense topic and can't be addressed in a single SO thread. I'd recommend reading some articles like Arnav Aggarwal's "React Ecosystem Setup - Step-By-Step Walkthrough" to see what typically goes into setting up React, Webpack, and Babel on your own. There are many other resources, and SO questions that will fill in any gaps or questions you have if you attempt your own dev environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will write the shortest tutorial :)

**Step1**: Create folder and file structure like below:
[image]

**Step2**: Install dependencies below:

```
npm install -S react react-dom prop-types
```

**Step3**: Install dev dependencies:

```
npm install -D babel-core babel-loader babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react html-webpack-plugin webpack
```

**Step4**: Add **index.html** file to root folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Mounting point for React VDOM-->
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Step5**: Create **webpack.config.js** file in root folder with content:

```
 let path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const PATHS = {
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    dist: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    main: path.join(__dirname, 'src/main.js')
}

let wpConfig = {
    entry: PATHS.main,
    output: {
        path: PATHS.dist,
        filename: 'build.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                  "presets": [
                      "es2015",
                      "react"
                   ],
                   "plugins": [
                      "transform-class-properties"
                   ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({ 
            title: 'My First React App',
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = wpConfig
```

**Step6**: Add nmp command. In **package.json** file go to **"scripts"** sections and add build command like below:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack"
  }
```

**Step7**: Create this simple React app file (**main.js**) in **src** folder:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello,</h1>
            <p>This is my first react app!</p>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**Step8**: Run command:

```
npm run build
```

Webpack will build and save files(**build.js** and **index.html**) to **dist** folder. Open your **/dist/index.html** file in browser and your first react app from zero is ready! Start with this basic app, then add some additional features like stylesheets (css, sass), router, webpack dev-server, hot reloading and etc.Happy coding!

Comment: Could you pls accept my answer if you are satisfied with it?

Comment: Lacking the web server setup (e.g. expressjs)

Comment: In the first step already gives error `failed to parse JSON` because package.json is empty

Answer (score 0):

`"build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack"` does not work
instead, ensure that `node` is included in the command:
`"build": "node node_modules/.bin/webpack"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35649642)